# Phonegap iOS app input not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have built a phonegap app with the sencha touch framework.
The app is "compiled" using the Phonegap Build service.
I have successfully deployed said app to my Windows and Android Smartphone.
Today I tried to deploy it to an Apple device.

There, the behaviour is really strange:

- The index.html is loaded, I can see the DOM in the web inspector on my Mac, and see that there are no errors displayed in the remote web console.
- The one thing that is not working, though, is input. I can't use the website, can't scroll, can't click links, can't input data into forms.
- The web site works in Safari browser on the phone (and obviously also in the Chrome WebView on Android).

Now I came to think:

- Could this behaviour be caused by an error I made in the construction of the development key and/or provisioning profile? (I guess no, when the app gets installed on the phone they have to be correct?)
- Could this behaviour be caused by a Sencha Touch error (I use 2.3.1 Build date 2014-01-08 14:23:30)?
- Could this behaviour be caused by a Safari bug? (I use Mozilla 5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.14 (KHTML, like Gecko, Version/8.0 Mobile/12F70 Safari/600.14)
- What else could cause this error?

Yes, I found [input not working in phonegap app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603442/input-not-working-in-phonegap-app) but the framework and the affected devices/builds are quite different.

Comment: Did you try to debug the issue with GapDebug? It'll tell you more errors then the XCode Console. 

- I think it can not be caused of a wrong profile. Like you said, if it would be a wrong profile the app wouldn't compile or even run on your device.

Comment: Try deploying the clean "demo" sencha touch project using the same phone gap settings and see if user interaction is working. If not the problem is with the phone gap settings, if yes there is a problem somewhere in your code.

Comment: Testing with the "clean demo sencha touch project", I found the issue to be in my config.xml.

Comment: The issue seems to be either `<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />` or `<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />` or both. I set both to true and it works.